Is the tidal force at the Roche Limit equivalent to the gravitational force of the body?
There is a pebble on the surface of the earth facing a massive celestial body. If the tidal force becomes equal to 9.81m/s^2, Then it will float.
Would this be at the Roche Limit then?
Does that mean the Roche Limit is when the tidal force is equivalent to the gravitational force of the host body?
I found this answer that seems to say this but in less clear words
Why aren't Roche limit and the difference in gravitational acceleration the same?

That is roughly the case.
Assuming an object of mass $m$ and radius $r$ at a distance $d$ from a body of mass $M$, then the  tidal acceleration across the object will be
$$ F_{\rm tidal} \simeq \frac{GM}{(d-r)^2} - \frac{GM}{(d + r)^2} \simeq \frac{4GMr}{d^3}\ . $$
From the point of view of the centre of mass of $m$, this means there is a stretching acceleration of $\pm 2GMr/d^3$ trying to pull it apart. This will succeed if
$$ \frac{2GMr}{d^3} > \frac{Gm}{r^2}\ ,$$
where the right hand side is the self-gravity of mass $m$, and hence
$$ d < 1.26 r\left(\frac{M}{m}\right)^{1/3}$$
and the right hand side could be called the Roche limit.
In practice it is more complicated. Firstly, if this is an orbiting system then there will be an additional centrifugal force and this also differs across the diameter of the body, helping it to break up, and increasing the Roche limit. This increases the numerical coefficient at the front of the equation above from $2^{1/3}$ to $3^{1/3}$ for something rotating in tidal synchronicity with its orbital period.
Secondly, it assumes that there is no tidal deformation. This will increase the value of $r$ along the line of centres, which increases the tidal acceleration and decreases the self-gravity, meaning that the Roche limit becomes larger again.

Eloquently put as ever. Thank you so much Professor.
